# Canceling ambient sound

Tags: audio, noise, speakers, sound, inverting-amplifier

I've just moved into a new flat and I noticed that there is a lot of car noise coming through windows. I know, I could just close the windows, but that's a less interesting approach to a problem. So last night, while trying to fall asleep, I started to wonder: Is there a device that could isolate me from noise coming from the outside?

I'm thinking of something that could listen to the sound coming in, invert it and then output the inverted sound through a speaker array, so they both cancel each other out.

Is there something like this on the market, or is it even possible?

Comment: 1) asking for certain products is **off-topic** 2) just Google: "Noise cancelling headphones", they've been around for a few years already. 3) noise cancelling is **a lot** more complex than just "inverting the signal". 4) It only works through headphones, not speakers, as through speakers reflections of the room etc. make cancelling the noise nearly impossible without full control of the room and the position of your ears.

Comment: Google is your friend. I suggest using it before asking questions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_noise_control

Comment: Bimpelrekkie but what if I would place my canceling speakers almost right at the noise source? This case the window from which the sound is comming from.

Comment: And where do you place your microphone?

Comment: just outside the window.

Comment: A cheaper, simpler option might be to add sound deadening insulation to the walls are ceiling around the room. This would attenuate sound reflecting around the room. Curtains would also do the same trick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called "Active Noise Control" (ANC) and apparently is not that uncommon. It is much harder to do in 3-D, but even that has been done to reduce noise in aircraft cabins and [automobiles](http://www.electronicdesign.com/automotive/reducing-unwanted-noise-automobiles).

If your noise source is localized (i.e. window) then ANC will be [more efficient](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-do-noise-cancellation-in-a-residential-room) and might be even simple enough for DIY project.

[Commercial solutions](https://www.silentium.com/) also available, but I suspect quite costly.

As a side note, while it was interesting reading and I don't regret spending time on this, you *really should have done it yourself* before asking question. It only took me 5 minutes to find the links above.